# Wordpress Menu: Menu items are added by latest items first

Tags: php, wordpress

Good Day

I am using a wordpress theme, and theme is adding menu items and ignores the Wordpress menu editor. The way it adds menu's is like this:

It adds all pages to the menu, and in the order you add the page - So if you want the first menu item to be last, you have to delete its page, and add it again - then it will appear as the last menu item.

How can I prevent this from happening and have control over my menu items?

relevant code - all places where the containing 'ul.dropdown' hosting the menu items appear:

**functions.php**:

```
// Add ID and CLASS attributes to the first <ul> occurence in wp_page_menu
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
return preg_replace('/<ul>/', '<ul class="reset dropdown">', $ulclass, 1);
}
```

and

**dropdown.php** - the whole file

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location'  => 'primary', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'container_class' => 'nav-menu',) ); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running WprdPress 3.0 or higher. For starters you ought to have `add_theme_support( 'menus' );` in your `functions.php` file this tells WordPress that the theme supports custom menus.

Then in order to display your menu, you would actually instruct WordPress to use the menu. using something similar to the following. You need to add the following code wherever you want the menu to appear.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
```

`wp_nav_menu` is the main function at work. The arguments `sort_column` tells WordPress to follow the order you pick in the options panel, and the argument `container_class` refers to the the CSS class that you assign to the menu.

Note that if you are using more than one menu (you may want to have a header and a footer menu for instance), you need to let Wordpress know how to identify the menu in question. You can do this by specifying either the menu ID, menu slug, or menu name using the following parameters `$id`, `$slug`or `$menu`.

I hope that helps. Should you wish to read more about this the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) is a great place to start.

Regards,
Ian

Comment: thank you, I did not specify 'Primary' and Secondary menus/navigations inside Menu editor. But this info is very useful thank you

Comment: Yes. You need to tell WoprdPress which menu to use where. The reason you were getting the menu showing with items in that order was because WordPress allows you to set a menu fallback - see `fallback_cb` in WP Codex. So probably your theme had a fallback for its menu system not to break your site :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance to be a plugin that you have?

Also there are some issues with the uploading in wordpress you must be carefull.

Do you use any ftp or do you do the changes at the editor of wordpress?

Comment: I only have one plugins installed: WordPress Importer. I do both editor and ftp changes...

Comment: Be careful with the upload also try to empty your cache every time you do the changes.

Comment: From clear browser history there is an option for that,also there is a plugin for wordpress but it is better not to confuse you with other useless for the moment things.